# Making interactive plot of time series rasterbrick using R

Tags: r, time-series, raster, interactive

My goal is to make an interactive plot of rain radar time serie, I want to is display the raster layer I want through a scroll bar in the plot area, or with HTML output like `dygraph` can do.

For now, I use the `raster`, `levelplot` and `animate` packages to make a gif of the event (with `sp` to add shapefile), but the result is not very good for my use of it, and not pretty.

Is that possible and how?

I tried to use the `htmlwidget` and `leaflet` without success. They do not allow the multiband raster except for RGB purpose. so when I tried, it gaves me the sum of all the layers in one.

I don't know what script I could give to help you. Ask me if you need something.

Comment: Maybe `plotly` + `rasterly` - https://z267xu.github.io/rasterly/

Comment: The `rasterly` package seems to only use data tables. It's not efficient here to turn raster in data table then in raster with `rasterly`. But thank you !

Comment: I recommend opening a new question, with a minimal dataset and example code of what works and doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to produce something that can better explain what I am trying to produce.
I think the interactive raster plot is more complicated than I thought and may not exist in R at the moment.
All I can find for now is `plotly/rasterly` or `ggplot` and from what I understand they only work with data frames.